# Difference between += and = 1+ in Java

Tags: java, recursion, graph, syntax, depth-first-search

Me and my friend have been working on a problem for school. We are traversing a graph with DFS and are counting the number of nodes in each given component. We get widely different results and have identified where the difference lies.

When going into the next recursion, my friend uses the syntax

```
componentSize += DFS_visit(nextNodeToVisit);
```

whereas I use

```
componentSize = 1 + DFS_visit(nextNodeToVisit);
```

I originally thought these two were the same, so what is the difference? And which one should be used in our case?

Comment: `a += b` is synonymous with `a = a + b`

Comment: They're only the same in the case where componentSize starts as 1.

Comment: The `+` operator has higher precedence than the `=` operator.  Therefore your statement reads `thing = (1 + thing)`.  Depending on the value of `thing` (if !=1) will yield an ‘unexpected’ result, hence the discrepancy.

Comment: `And which one should be used in our case?` ... obviously the one that produces correct results

Comment: @jsotola Yes thank you for your insightful answer. The right method is always the correct solution ...

Comment: @S3DEV and jonrsharpe Thank you for good explanations!:D

Comment: just note that `a += b` is not exactly the same as `a = a + b` - the first one includes an implicit cast and `a` is only evaluated once! [JLS 15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 componentSize += DFS_visit(nextNodeToVisit);
```

means

```
 componentSize = componentSize + DFS_visit(nextNodeToVisit);
```

Compare that with

```
 componentSize = DFS_visit(nextNodeToVisit) + 1;
```

See the difference?

In general  `a <op>= b` means roughly the same as `a = a <op> b` where `<op>` an operator.  (There is also a typecast of the LHS to the type of `a`.)

---

> And which one should be used in our case?

It is not clear which is correct.  We would need to see the data structure and more of the algorithm.